# Exchange transport agent to check senders of email message

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-transport-agents

I would like to write an Exchange transport agent to check email message senders against a text file and based on that change email subject line. What would be C#  code to check email senders? Should it be something like this?

```
List<RoutingAddress> emails = new List<RoutingAddress>();
RoutingAddress john = new RoutingAddress("john@contoso.com");
emails.Add(john);
     if (emails.Contains(e.MailItem.FromAddress))
         e.MailItem.Message.Subject = "EmailGroup1";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to use a HashSet instead for this to work...